# IP address is associated with the wrong interface

Tags: c, linux, ip

I have a problem, and i can't solve this issue.

I have 3 Ethernet boards in my computer, and in 2 of 3 ports have a cable plugged. Follow the List:

> Eth0 - Cable Plugged.
>   Eth1 - No Cable.
>   Eth2 - Cable Plugged.

When I run my program to get ip address of the interfaces, my program set the IP of eth2 to eth1, and what was supposed to be like this:

> eth0 - 192.168.2.103
>   eth1 - (null)
>   eth2 - 192.168.2.101

ends like this:

> eth0 - 192.168.2.103
>   eth1 - 192.168.2.101
>   eth2 - (null)

I can't understand what's going on.
Follow the code:

I have and struct;

```
typedef struct iface {
    char interface_name[10];
    char interface_addr_ipv4[20];
    char interface_addr_ipv6[40];
    char interface_netmask[20];
    char interface_broadcast[20];
    char interface_mac_addr[50];
    int interface_active;
    struct iface * next_interface;

 } Interface;
```

After this, I identify all ifaces of system in this way, even if they are not configured with an IP:

```
if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1)
    return GET_INFO_IFACES_FAILED;

struct iface * iface_aux;
struct ifaddrs * ifaddr_aux;
struct sockaddr_in * ip;

iface_aux = iface;
for (ifaddr_aux=ifaddr;ifaddr_aux!=NULL;ifaddr_aux=ifaddr_aux->ifa_next) {
    iface_aux->interface_name = ifaddr_aux->ifa_name;

    if (ip->sin_family == AF_PACKET) {
        get_interface_mac_addr(iface_aux);
        strcpy(iface_aux->interface_addr_ipv4,"");
        strcpy(iface_aux->interface_addr_ipv6,"");
        iface_aux->next_interface = malloc(sizeof (Interface));
        iface_aux = iface_aux->next_interface;
        iface_aux->next_interface = NULL;
    }
}
```

After all this, I do other loop to get ip address of interfaces, this is the code:

```
iface_aux = iface; //go to the firts pointer
for (ifaddr_aux=ifaddr;ifaddr_aux!=NULL;ifaddr_aux=ifaddr_aux->ifa_next) {
    ip = (struct sockaddr_in *) ifaddr_aux->ifa_addr;
    if (ip->sin_family == AF_INET) {
        get_interface_ifaddr(iface_aux, ip);
        get_interface_netmask(iface_aux, ifaddr);
        get_interface_broadcast(iface_aux, ifaddr);
        iface_aux = iface_aux->next_interface;
    }
}
```

The code of function get_interface_ifaddr is:

```
int get_interface_ifaddr(Interface * iface, struct sockaddr_in * ip) {
    char temp[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &ip->sin_addr, temp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    strcpy(iface->interface_addr_ipv4, temp);
    return GET_IPADDR_SUCCESS;
}
```

I can't understand why the ip of eth2 is set in eth1, and to see what's happened. When I debug the code with netbeans and GDB and I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Why don't you fill in the IP address in the first loop, instead of two different loops?

Comment: Because i get all interfaces, even the not configured yet, and after i get the ip of configured interfaces.

Comment: That's the problem. Since the 2nd loop doesn't get all interfaces, its loop is out of sync with the `iface` linked list. You need to check whether the interface name matches; if not, go to the next interface.

Comment: You are right man, sorry;

Comment: @Barmar, you should write that up as an answer.